# Stopping nifi processor without wait/notify processor and curl commands

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to terminate `invokhttp` processor as soon as it fails, for that I use `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor I have made bat  file  with code like this:

```
curl  http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/process-groups/root/processors/f511a6a1-015d-1000-970e-969eac1e6fc5'-X PUT -H 'Accept: application/json'-d @stop.json -vv
```

and I  have related json file with code like this:

```
{
  "status": {
    "runStatus": "STOPPED"
  },
  "component": {
    "state": "STOPPED",
    "id": "f511a6a1-015d-1000-970e-969eac1e6fc5"
  },
  "id": "f511a6a1-015d-1000-970e-969eac1e6fc5",
  "revision": {
    "version": 30,
    "clientId": "0343f0b9-015e-1000-7cd8-570f8953ec11"
  }
}
```

I use my `jso` file as an argument for command inside `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor bat  it throws an exception  like this:

1. What should I  change?

[image]

Comment: response 404 not found. probably you have wrong url specified. check the nifi-api documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/

Comment: The base URL path for the processor resource is `/nifi-api/processors/...`, so try taking out the `.../controller/process-groups/root/...` part of the path you are using.

Comment: I  have tried it but  prosessor  still throws the same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all actions in nifi that you can do through web browser you can do through nifi-api.

- use google chrome you can press `F12` to activate `DevTools` 
  (other browsers also has this option)
- then select Network tab
- do required action on nifi (for example stop the processor)
- right-click the request and choose menu `copy -> copy as cUrl (bash)`

now you have curl command in clipboard that repeats the same nifi action through calling nifi-api

you can remove all headers parameters (-H) except one: `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

so the stop action for my processor will look like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/processors/d03bbf8b-015d-1000-f7d6-2f949d44cb7f' -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"revision":{"clientId":"09dbb50e-015e-1000-787b-058ed0938d0e","version":1},"component":{"id":"d03bbf8b-015d-1000-f7d6-2f949d44cb7f","state":"STOPPED"}}'
```

**beware!** every time you change processor (even state) its version changes.

so before sending `stop` request you have to get current version & state.

you have to sent GET request to the same url as above without any additional headers:

```
http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/processors/d03bbf8b-015d-1000-f7d6-2f949d44cb7f
```

where `d03bbf8b-015d-1000-f7d6-2f949d44cb7f` is id of your processor.
you can just try this url in browser but replace the processor id in it.

the response will be in json.

```
{"revision":
  {"clientId":"09dbb50e-015e-1000-787b-058ed0938d0e","version":4},
  "id":"d03bbf8b-015d-1000-f7d6-2f949d44cb7f",
  "uri": 
  ...a lot of information here about this processor... 
}
```

you can take `clientId` and `version` from result and use those attributes to build correct `STOP` request. 
[image]

**PS:**

- `ExecuteStreamCommand` transfers flow file into executing command as an input stream that could cause problems

  - use `ExecuteProcess` because you passing all the parameters to curl in command line and not through input stream.
- you can stop the nifi processor without using curl - you just need to build correct sequence of processors like this:

  - `InvokeHTTP (get current state)` -> `EvaluateJsonPath (extract version and clientId)` -> `ReplaceText (build json for stop using attrs from prev step)` -> `InvokeHTTP (call stop)`
- try to avoid the logic of stopping processor from nifi - sure it's possible. just re-think your algorithm.

Comment: thank you i  made it  without  curl via  InvokeHTTP (get current state) -> EvaluateJsonPath (extract version and clientId) -> ReplaceText (build json for stop using attrs from prev step) -> InvokeHTTP (call stop) and  it  works  perfectly

Comment: but i added  executescript  for making json content  for  put  requst

Answer (score 0):

here  is  template  which  show  how  to stop invokehttp  processor :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uv14kuvk2evy9an/StopInvokeHttpPoceesor.xml?dl=0

Comment: without wait/notify processor and  rest api